# Scriptish / Greasemonkey GM_setValue and GM_getValue equivalents for Google Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage, content-script

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extension which basically has two different content scripts in it for two different domains (let's say *google.com* and *yahoo.com*):

**manifest.json**

```
...
"content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["https://*google.com/*"],
        "js": ["my_google.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"  
}, {
        "matches" : ["https://*yahoo.com/*"],
        "js": ["my_yahoo.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"  
}],

"permissions": ["storage"],  
...
```

I need a permanent (not just for one session) storage where both these scripts could update and retrieve some commonly shared data. I know, this can be done with [chrome.storage API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.set( { 'string1' : 'value1'}, function(){ 
    console.log("string1 with value = value1 has been added to the chrome.storage");  
    // continue with script code...
});

chrome.storage.local.get( 'string1', function (data){ 
    console.log("string1 with value = " + data['string1'] + " has been retrieved from the chrome.storage" );
    // continue with script code... 
});

chrome.storage.local.remove( 'string1', function () {
    console.log("string1 has been removed from chrome.storage") ;
    // continue with script code... 
});
```

Now, comes the funny part...

Is there any replacement for this API which would work like cross-domain chrome.storage but with **synchronous** calls to it? What I'm actually trying to achieve is to reproduce the behavior of Scriptish/Greasemonkey GM_setValue and GM_getValue APIs without need to change the whole code of both scripts previously used in Mozilla Firefox and now transferred to Google Chrome.

optionally:
also, it would be nice to be able to remove string1 (or probably clear all storage) from browser action icon pop-up page - popup.html (popup.js) .

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no synchronous cross-domain storage mechanism for content scripts.

However, if you *really* want to get such a feature, then you could implement such a storage yourself, by maintaining a local copy of the storage backed by [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html).

1. Initialization: Use [`chrome.storage.local.get(null, callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get) to fetch all stored data and store it in a local variable.
2. Maintenance:

   - Use the [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#event-onChanged) event to watch for changes and update the local copy when needed.
   - Whenever `GM_setValue` (etc.) is used, immediately update the local copy, so that calling `GM_getValue` immediately after `GM_setValue` gives the expected result.

Ideally, you should defer the execution of the other scripts until the storage is initialized. If this is not possible, create a separate script, and let it `"run_at": "document_start"`. Using this method, it's likely (although not guaranteed) that the storage is ready when the rest of your code runs at "document_end"`.

---

There is *another* way to synchronously get/set storage values. I **strongly, strongly discourage you from using this method**. Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` together with the webRequest API ([`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest)) can be used to communicate data from the background page to the content script, and vice versa.
Sending data is trivial (e.g. set a value in the URL),
getting data back is a bit more difficult. You can use `URL.createObjectURL` to get a `blob:` URL of your data, and return `{redirectUrl: ...}` to reply the just-created URL in the content script.